# Gpd as a presheaf category

Tags: category-theory

I wonder if there exists a way to see the category of groupoids Gpd as (isomorphic to, or maybe just equivalent to) a presheaf category (valued in Set) ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you expect that to be possible?

Comment: Sure! It's the category of presheaves of groupoids over a point.

Comment: "(valued in Set) "

Comment: It was a joke. ${}$

Comment: I have a proof that $\mathsf{Gpd}$ has no subobject classifier, and hence is no presheaf category. But it is long and clumsy. I don't want to post it in the present form.

Comment: @Martin: interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any category $\mathcal{C}$, the presheaf category $[\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$ is a regular category. In particular, the class of regular epimorphisms is closed under pullback in $[\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$. However, this is not true in $\mathbf{Grpd}$.

Indeed, let $\mathbb{I} = \{ 0 \cong 1 \}$ be the groupoid with two objects and a unique isomorphism between them. Let $\mathbb{A} = \mathbb{I} \amalg \mathbb{I}$. There is an evident regular epimorphism $\mathbb{A} \to \mathbb{B}$ obtained by identifying one copy of $1$ with the disjoint copy of $0$; so $\mathbb{B} = \{ 0 \cong 1 \cong 2 \}$ is the groupoid with three objects and a unique isomorphism between any pair of objects. Let $\mathbb{B}'$ be the subgroupoid $\{ 0 \cong 2 \} \subset \mathbb{B}$, and consider the evident pullback diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{A}^\prime @>>> \mathbb{A} \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\mathbb{B}^\prime @>>> \mathbb{B} 
\end{CD}$$
Clearly, $\mathbb{A}'$ is the discrete groupoid with two objects, and therefore the morphism $\mathbb{A}' \to \mathbb{A}$ is not a regular epimorphism.

Exactly the same argument shows $\mathbf{Cat}$ is not a regular category.

Comment: It looks like two clauses got switched in the third sentence of the second paragraph-you mention the regular epi onto $B$ before you define it.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: No, $A \to B$ is defined to be the coequalizer of two morphisms $\star \rightrightarrows A$. What follows, $B = \{0 \cong 1 \cong 2\}$, is a description of $B$, not the definition.

Comment: Ah, yes, got it.